# Full path of project

Tags: cocoa, swift

I want to open a text file in Swift and I managed to do it passing the full path as parameter:

```
let dados = String.stringWithContentsOfFile("/Users/aczuquim/Google Drive/Swift/Verdadeiro ou Falso/Verdadeiro ou Falso/Dados.txt", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

Since, I added the file to the project, is there any way to use relative path?

When I use the relative path, a `nil` is returned.

**UPDATE**

In the playground, the line bellow works fine:

```
let dados = String.stringWithContentsOfFile("/Users/aczuquim/Google Drive/Swift/Verdadeiro ou Falso/Verdadeiro ou Falso/dados.txt", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

But not the following ones (`path` is `nil`):

```
let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let path = bundle.pathForResource("dados", ofType: "txt")
```

Comment: I assume it is copied into the Resources directory while building i.e. it has been added to 'Copy Bundle Resources' under 'Build Phases' in your project settings ??

Comment: And you want to access the file in your Resources directory and not in your project(both are different)?

Comment: Project and Resources directory are the same. But if I not use the full path, I can't read the file. And I don't want to hard code the full path directory (want to use relative path instead)

Comment: Project and Resources directory are NOT the same. The path you have given is your project directory. To go to the Resources directory, right-click the corresponding target and click 'Show in Finder'. Right-click the app and click 'Show Package Contents'. A little searching inside that and you should find the 'Resources' directory

Comment: The file is copied from your project to this Resources directory while building so that it stays with your app always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Bundle resource:

**Swift 3.0**

```
if let bundle = Bundle.main().urlForResource("Info", withExtension: "plist") {
    print("Path: \(bundle)")
}
```

**Swift 2.0**

```
let bundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle()!.URLForResource("dados", withExtension: "txt")
        println("\(bundleURL)")
```

If a nil is returned then the resource is not found and an error reported (note the exclamation mark after `mainBundle`). Check Build Phases - Copy Bundle Resources if the resource is being included.

### App and Documents Folder

Get the documents folder from an array of `[AnyObject]!` which casts the first object to the `NSURL` type:

```
let docFolderURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as NSURL
        println("DocumentFolderURL: \(docFolderURL)")
```

Then get the App folder, by stepping up to the parent folder and delete the last path component:

```
let appFolderURL = docFolderURL.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent
println("AppFolderURL: \(appFolderURL)")
```

Other directories may be accessed by using `.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent: String?, isDirectory:Bool)` etc.

### Temporary Directory

```
var tempURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true).URLByDeletingLastPathComponent
```

Note that Apple now prefers the use of **URL´s** to access folders and files and new methods use them exclusively. To use the path in older methods just call: `tempURL.path`

Comment: It did the trick. It only works in the application, but not in the playground. This makes sense since the playground works independent of compilation. Right?

Comment: Your probably right, the playground is not compiled into an App